# Upgrade all databases using one upgraded database ik one local SQL instance

Tags: sql-server, upgrade

Situation : MICROSOFT SQL SERVER 2019 server , for testing I use express version.

An app is linked to one local SQL instance , let name this instance ‘ Appname’ .

In this instance there is a database , let’s call it ‘root database’. And the instance contain more databases ( can be 100 , even more ) .

So each of these databases contain data , each of them gets data from the App user works with.

The data does not change if an upgrade is needed.

the ‘root database’needs to be upgraded once a while ( data stays the same but the schemes , etc .. , needs to be upgraded)

How can I use Microsoft studio manager to upgrade all other databases using upgraded ‘root database’? So they all have same changes ( schemes , .. ) ?

How to use CMD to get the same results and maybe this method will upgrade all databases faster ?

Answer (score -2):

I would follow this path:

1. Generate dacpac from the root database if you don't have already a dacpac as update.
2. Generate a scirpt of [sqlpackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver15) commands using that dacpac as source, having one command for each target database.
3. Execute those commands.

In this way you can create a dacpac from your root database:

```
sqlpackage.exe
    /action:extract
    /targetservername:server_name 
    /targetdatabasename:root_database_name
    /targetfile:"<path>\root_database_name.dacpac"
```

then you have to apply it to each database you need.
To apply a dacpac to a database you have to use this command

```
<path>\SqlPackage.exe
    /Action:Publish
    /SourceFile:"<path>\root_database_name.dacpac"
    /TargetDatabaseName:db_name
    /TargetServerName:server_name
```

You should have a a way to select all database you have to applay that dacpac

```
select name  from sys.databases where name like 'mydb%' -- or another filter you have
```

so if you puth all together, you can do something like this:

```
select
'<path>\SqlPackage.exe
    /Action:Publish
    /SourceFile:"<path>\root_database_name.dacpac"
    /TargetDatabaseName:' + name +'
    /TargetServerName:server_name'
from sys.databases where name like 'mydb%'
```

In the query output you will have all the commands needed.

This is an easy option. Probably there are better...
Hope to be of help.